# multiple view handle by one controller in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, ionic-framework

i am new to ionic programming, i have searched a lot but not getting answer that close to my requirement. If angular follow close to mvc( i know MVVM ), then must be a way to handle multiple view by one controller .

I have multiple view on login process like slider view , login and sign up view and validate OTP etc.

Comment: handling multiple view is followed by **.config**  in angularjs and ofcourse you can write your login for the entire application in a single controller but it is not a good way of practicing.

Comment: Got it , Thanks for suggestion .